# Computer crashes due to playing internet video

Tags: windows-xp, video, flash

Trying to play a Flash video makes my computer reboot.  This also happens with videos with a '.mov' extension.

Answer (score 1):

The first step would be to update your video driver.  Also, running systems diagnostics to rule out hardware failure would be a good idea.